# How to make page numbering continuous after a second \mainmatter?

Tags: page-numbering, front-matter

I am writing a document with multiple `\mainmatter`s and `\backmatter`s.
The structure is basically:

```
...
\mainmatter
\backmatter
...
\mainmatter
\backmatter
...
```

Is there a simple way of preventing LaTeX to reset the page counter?
Also `\backmatter` should not reset the counter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the purpose of alternating `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`?

Comment: Thank you :) The purpose is, that i have multiple documents, each with its own reference list, which i must summarize in tex using the book class. Since references should be listed in the backmatter multiple backmatters/mainmatter are necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This depends highly on the document class you're using. Taking the standard [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) as base, `\fontmatter` and `\mainmatter` both reset the page counter. `\backmatter` on the other hand doesn't:

```
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \@mainmatterfalse}
```

The important thing that causes the page numbering to be reset when issuing the above commands is `\pagenumbering` (taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \global\c@page \@ne \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname
   \c@page}}
```

As mentioned, this sets the page counter to one (`\global\c@page \@ne`) and redefines the representation `\thepage` (`\gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname\c@page}`). So, with an issue of `\pagenumbering{roman}` (as is performed by `\frontmatter`), LaTeX issues something equivalent to

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
```

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) does something similar. If your question is *only* "How to prevent LaTeX from resetting the page counter?", then you should not use `\frontmatter` and friends, or at least void what `\pagenumbering` is doing. You might just be better off redefining the page counter printing mechanism `\thepage` as is done above. Or, for convenience of use in order to stick to your current layout, perhaps the following suffices in your preamble (which removes the page counter resetting):

```
\makeatletter
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname \c@page}}
\makeatother
```

Finally, neither `book` nor `memoir` resets the page counter for `\backmatter`.

Comment: Wouldn't `\def\pagenumbering#1{}` be more economic? :) However, redefining `\mainmatter` seems to be better than changing drastically the meaning of an important command.

Comment: @egreg: If the OP doesn't want to change to a different numbering representation (like roman or arabic), then yes.

Answer (score 10):

An easy solution to your problem is getting rid of the `\pagenumbering` command issued by `\mainmatter`, which is responsible of resetting the page number. So I propose

```
\makeatletter
\def\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \def\mainmatter{\cleardoublepage\@mainmattertrue}
}
\makeatother
```

The first call of `\mainmatter` would do as usual, so the page numbering will be arabic, starting from 1. Then it redefines itself to issue only `\cleardoublepage` and `\@mainmattertrue`. The latter restores chapter numbering.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for a `\mainmatter` command without reset:

```
\newcommand\mainmatterWithoutReset
 {\edef\temppagenumber{\arabic{page}}%
  \mainmatter
  \setcounter{page}{\temppagenumber}%
 }
```

The command stores the current value of the page counter in the macro `\temppagenumber`, then executes `\mainmatter`, which resets the page counter as a side effect of changing the page number style to arabic, and finally resets the page counter to its original value.

To use the new `\mainmatter` under its old name, define it this way:

```
\let\mainmatterorig\mainmatter
\renewcommand\mainmatter
 {\edef\temppagenumber{\arabic{page}}%
  \mainmatterorig
  \setcounter{page}{\temppagenumber}%
 }
```