# Continuous page numbering in book class

Tags: page-numbering

In the LaTeX `book` class, I would like to have my page numbers start at one on the title page, and continue in arabic numbers all the way through to the end of the index.

I find that the `\mainmatter` command, in addition to starting section numbering, also resets the page numbers.

After reading [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61424/how-to-make-page-numbering-continuous-after-a-second-mainmatter) I tried running this in my preamble:

```
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue}
```

But I ended up with:

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m 
l.45 \mainmatter

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I achieve my aim of continuous numbering?

Comment: Do you have a `\frontmatter` instruction after `\begin{document}`? If so, just omit the `\frontmatter` instruction.

Comment: any command containing an `@` sign is "internal" and has to be treated specially.  just wrap this definition in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` and that will get rid of the error message.  whether it will give the result you're looking for is untested.

Comment: Brilliant, yes @barbarabeeton that fixed it (although not in the `renewcommand` macro for some reason - I just included `\makeatletter\@mainmattertrue\makeatother 
\cleardoublepage` where I used to have `\mainmatter`).

Comment: @BillCheatham -- since `\mainmatter` is usually used just before the first chapter, if you leave it there unchanged, you will get duplicate page numbers.  the change you made (omitting `\pagenumbering{arabic}`) gets rid of that problem.

Comment: an easy way is to add `\renewcommand*\pagenumbering[1]{}`