# How to numerate a page with table of contents?

Tags: page-numbering

I  make my diploma and want to end-to-end numbering of my document.

But I have an error with page with table of contents. For example:

1st page - title page

2nd page - Abstract (I manually fix it's number to 2)

3td page - Contents (I can't numerate it to 3, it stubbornly spelled 'i')

4th page - Intro and following text...

Can you please help me to numerate page with table of contents? Thank you))

I have the following code for beginning pages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[noheader]{sleek}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
title page
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\begin{center}
\section{Abstract}
\end{center}
About purposes...

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{3}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Content}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\romantableofcontents


\setcounter{page}{4}
\begin{center}
\section{Intro}
\end{center}
lalala

\end{document}
```

And code for sleek.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackage{sleek}[2020/10/29 v1.01 Sleek Package]

% Table of contents

\newcommand{\romantableofcontents}{ % creates a table of contents with roman (i, ii, iii, ...) numbering of the pages
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}

\endinput
```

Comment: Please make a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that people can copy-paste and test your code. Your choice of document class and packages will greatly influence how pages are numbered by default.

Comment: `\large` does not take a argument so `\large{...} ...`  is making the entire document large not just the text in `{...}`

Comment: You have not provided any code we can test but `\setcounter{page}{3}\pagenumbering{arabic}` is wrog as `\pagenumbering` sets the number to 1, so you keep repeating that command so prevent latex numbering the pages

Comment: @David Carlisle
I tried to increase text but only Large helped

Comment: @David Carlisle, I have only this minimal code... First page is file.pdf

Comment: but you have the syntax wrong it should be `\Large abc` not `\Large{abc}`

Comment: I tried to fix \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}, but it doesn't change anything/

Comment: Provide an example that shows the problem then people can suggest fixes.  Remove every package not needed to show the problm and every package that stops latex with: `! LaTeX Error: File \`packages/sleek.sty' not found.`

Comment: ok, can we move this discussion to chat? I can't share here files

Comment: Do not share files, just fix your example code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following code to your `sleek.sty`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname \c@page}}
\makeatother
```

from [this TeX.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61473/199568), which seems to have worked fine. Here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sleek.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{sleek}[2020/10/29 v1.01 Sleek Package]

% New code:
%===============================================
\makeatletter
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname \c@page}}
\makeatother
%===============================================

% Table of contents

\newcommand{\romantableofcontents}{ % creates a table of contents with roman (i, ii, iii, ...) numbering of the pages
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{sleek}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
title page
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\begin{center}
\section{Abstract}
\end{center}
About purposes...

\newpage

\renewcommand\contentsname{Content}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
\romantableofcontents
\newpage


\setcounter{page}{4}
\begin{center}
\section{Intro}
\end{center}
lalala

\end{document}
```

I also removed the `\setcounter{page}{3} \pagenumbering{arabic}` which was redundant. The nice thing about this is that if you chose to move the table of contents to another page, the numbering will still be right.

---

Also: in the future I recommend using `\begin{filecontents}{<filename>}` to include files (like `.bib`, `.sty` and `.cls`) in your MWE. It makes it much easier for us to run and test the MWE.

Comment: thanks for your help. But can I clarify: how to make 14pt without using \large? At least, there is no any sleek files, but \documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article} dont't help(((

Comment: See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70384/199568 . To get ``14pt`` you can use: ``\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}``